# Expose Jupyter Kernel to Python 2

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, kernel, jupyter-notebook, conda

I've created two anaconda3 environments:

```
conda create -n py3 python=3 anaconda
conda create -n py2 python=2 anaconda
```

if I follow these steps:

```
source activate py3
(py3)$ jupyter notebook
```

it works.

but If I activate py2 and install kernel inside its environment:

```
source activate py2
(py2)$ ipython kernel install
(py2)$ jupyter notebook
```

kernel fails to start..

what am I missing here?

**EDIT**

parcial Traceback:

```
     File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1025, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you made sure you have installed python on both the environments!?

Comment: yes I'm positive